# Copying a sheet moves legend in chart

Tags: excel, vba

I am using Excel VBA to create copies of a "MASTER" sheet and fill each copy with different settings (and data).

I have several charts on the master sheet and when copying it, (only) one of them gets copied incorrectly - its legend moves around. 
In my original chart, it is custom-positioned (none of the xlBottom or similar) and when copied, the legend moves to another position (always the same one, appears as only the left property gets changed).

Since I later export the charts into a standardized presentation, this poses a problem.

I have failed to find any advice or in fact anyone with a similar problem.

The code I use to copy the sheet (prior to this, I delete any previous occurences of the sheet bearing the same name):

```
astrSheetName = "SomeName" 'This is actually an input into the function

Set wsMaster = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("MASTER")
wsMaster.Copy After:=wsMaster
ActiveSheet.Name = astrSheetName
ActiveSheet.Tab.ColorIndex = -4142
```

I would appreciate any help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a bug in Excel if you have the legend in a custom position. To fix this you need to define the legend's position in your code. The blurb below is an example of how to do this.

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
ActiveChart.Legend.Select
Selection.Left = 32.016
Selection.Top = 190.917
```

Comment: I thought about something like this, but the solution didn't look "nice" to me :) Anyway, looks like there will be no choice left.
Thank you for your answer !